# why overriding a variable is not allowed in scala

Tags: scala

### case 1: override var i to change visibility

It only works when both `Test1.i` and `Test1Scala.i` are `val`, otherwise resulta in a compile error: "variable i cannot override a mutable variable".

```
package test
class Base1 {
  private[test] var i = 0
}
class Child1Scala extends Base1 {
  override var i = 1
}
```

This limitation can be bypassed by using java

```
class Child1Java extends Base1 {
    @Override public int i() {
        return super.i();
    }
    @Override public void i_$eq(int value) {
        super.i_$eq(value);
    }
}
```

---

### case 2: override var i to add some code for logging

Doesn't work at all, neither `var` nor `val`. It always results in a compile error: "super may not be used on variable i". But without `super`, there methods will become infinite tail call

```
class Base2 {
  var i = 0
}
class Child2Scala extends Base2 {
  override def i: Int = {
    println("get")
    super.i
  }
  override def i_=(value: Int): Unit = {
    println("set")
    super.i = value
  }
}
```

Again, it's legal in java

```
class Child2Java extends Base2 {
    @Override public int i() {
        System.out.println("get i");
        return super.i();
    }
    @Override public void i_$eq(int value) {
        System.out.println("set i");
        super.i_$eq(value);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Why do you need to override a var? You should avoid using mutable variables wherever possible. This isn't Java.

Comment: You should not use vars. Let lone override them.